# Is there any options to make clang-format produce the following effect?

Tags: c++, c++11, ide, clang, clang-format

I use clang-format to format the following code, but the effect is not what I want:

```
void f(int, int, std::vector<int>, std::map<int, int>)
{}

int main()
{
    f(
        {
    },
        {}, {1, 2, 3},
        {
            {1, 2},
            {3, 4},
        });
}
```

**Is there any options to make clang-format produce the following effect?**

```
void f(int, int, std::vector<int>, std::map<int, int>)
{}

int main()
{
    f({}, 
      {}, 
      {1, 2, 3},
      {
          {1, 2},
          {3, 4},
      });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is, use the *style* you want. (it's really that easy!)

`clang-format -h` tells you about the available options that clang-format has.

> ```
>   --style=<string>           - Coding style, currently supports:
>                                  LLVM, GNU, Google, Chromium, Microsoft, Mozilla, WebKit.
>                                Use -style=file to load style configuration from
>                                .clang-format file located in one of the parent
>                                directories of the source file (or current
>                                directory for stdin).
> ```

In your case, you probably want something like `clang-format --style=LLVM`.

But it's not going to be *exactly* what you want. So, you'll need to write your own style file. It's not that hard. Use `clang-format --style=file` and put the style definitions in a file called `.clang-format` in the same, or one of its parent directories.

The [documentation](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html) explains exactly what you need to do. If you're more of the visual type, [this](https://zed0.co.uk/clang-format-configurator/) generator might be helpful.

Note, though, that you're probably better off making only minor adjustments to a "common" base style; other programmers might not like it when you do wildly different than other code they're used to. For an example of a modified-as-far-as-necessary-to-deal-with-specific-project-needs style file, see GNU Radio's [`.clang-format`](https://github.com/gnuradio/gnuradio/blob/master/.clang-format) file.